# Regressão não linear com variáveis dummie

Tags: r, regressão

Estou criando vários modelos, para depois fazer a seleção com base no AICc.
Dentre esses modelos que estou criando, tenho uma variável preditora categórica (fogo) que preciso incluí-la no modelo de regressão não linear. Os três modelos que preciso rodar são:

```
fire_vertical <- nls(R~0.23-exp(A*lnNt+C)+d*fire,
                     start=list(A=-0.33,C=0.45,d=-0.001),trace=T)

fire_lateral <- nls(R~0.23-exp((A*lnNt)+(C+d*fire)),
                    start=list(A=-0.33,C=0.45,d=-0.001),trace=T)

fire_nonlinear <- nls(R~0.23-exp((A+d*fire)*lnNt+C),
                      start=list(A=-0.33,C=0.45,d=-0.001),trace=T)
```

Considerando os seguintes dados:

```
R <- c(0.02,0.00,-0.06,0.11,0.06,0.00,-0.05,-0.06,
       0.02,-0.26,0.00,0.07,-0.07,0.23,0.06,-0.14,-0.04,
       0.09,-0.09,0.09,-0.02)

lnNt <- c(6.14,6.14,5.76,6.42,6.81,
          6.81,6.49,6.14,6.24,4.81,4.81,5.14,
          4.81,6.03,6.42,5.59,5.39,5.90,5.39,5.90,5.76)

fire <- c("before","before","before",
          "before","before","before",
          "before","afterone","afterone","afterone",
          "afterone","afterone","afterone","afterone",
          "aftertwo","aftertwo","aftertwo","aftertwo","aftertwo",
          "aftertwo","aftertwo")
```

Onde `lnNt` é uma variável preditora contínua, enquanto o fogo é um preditor categórico com três níveis: `before`, `afterone`, `aftertwo`.
Preciso transformar o fogo em uma variável dummie e fazer com que os três modelos apresentados rodem dessa forma.

Quem puder ajudar, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Em vez de transformar em dummy, transforme em `factor` e experimente ver o que dá. Quase todas (ou mesmo todas) as funções de modelação do R reconhecem carateres ou fatores e criam automaticamente os dummies, não é necessário fazẽ-lo manualmente

Comment: Mas se quiser criar os dummies, veja o pacote [dummies](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dummies) ou o pacote [dummy](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=dummy).

Comment: Olá Rui. Tentei fazer como você sugeriu, mas não foi possível rodar nenhum dos modelos. Apareceu a seguinte mensagem de erro: "Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
  Obtido valor faltante ou infinito quando avaliando o modelo
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(d, fire) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(d, fire) : ‘*’ not meaningful for factors"